# How do you put a window back as a tab in IE9 once you've undocked it?

Tags: user-interface, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, browser-tabs

I occasionally accidentally `undock` a tab from IE9 so it's in its own window (no idea what I'm doing to do this).

How do I get the window back as a tab in my main IE window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag the undocked tab (by the tab, not the window's title bar) so that the window disappears.  Move the tab between two tabs on another IE9 window and drop it.

Comment: Thanks!  I can confirm that this works on IE11 as well.  Also, you don’t have to  move the undocked tab *between* two tabs; you can put it to the left of the left-most one or to the right of the right-most one. … …  Note: I can get this to work only for a fully undocked / isolated tab; i.e., one that’s in a window by itself.  If you have tabs A and C in window 1 and tabs X, B, Y and Z in window 2, it’s a two-step process: undock tab B from window 2 and then insert it into window 1.

Comment: The same trick works in Firefox (54.0.1), although the UI is a little less smooth — you have to drag the tab that you're moving down to the taskbar button of the window you're moving it to.  (And of course you cannot join regular and private tabs in the same window.)

Answer (score -1):

have the mouse arrow on top of the tab. Then click on the right click of the mouse. See “pin tab”. Click on that. Then drag the tab onto the original window.

Comment: I know the question is about IE9, but, for the record: the accepted answer works on IE11, and this one does not.  (Or I just don’t understand how to do it.)